# Existe em MVC algo que seja equivalente ao <asp:repeater> do Web Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, mvc, framework

Estou montando um formulário onde alguns campos podem ou não se repetir, exemplo:

> Curso 1:

- Curso `[input text]`
- Instituição `[input text]`
- Ano conclusão `[input text]`

> Curso 2:

- Curso `[input text]`
- Instituição `[input text]`
- Ano conclusão `[input text]`

> Curso ...(n):

Em WebForms eu usaria um `asp:repeater` e pegaria o resultado pelo submit do form, em `MVC` existe algo equivalente para que eu possa pegar os valores inseridos nesses `inputs dinâmicos` ao dar `submit` na página? Caso não exista, poderiam me indicar um caminho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você especificar o nome do input assim `name="exemplo[]"`, e no controller colocar assim `(string[] exemplo)`, ele irá entender. Tenta assim para ver.

Answer (score 0):

Ola @Deividson, pelo que entendi você tem uma lista de cursos quer colocar seus elementos no html, bom para para isso você pode estar usando um foreach e construindo sua estrutura

```
@foreach(var curso in lstCursos){
  curso.Curso
  curso.Instituição
  curso.Ano conclusão
}
```

Comment: Eu formulei mal a pergunta, a questão não é `imprimir` em tela os valores vindos do Controller, mas sim, enviar os valores `inputados` na tela para o Controller ao dar Submit. Lembrando que, como uma pessoa pode ter 1 ou vários cursos realizados esses campos são dinâmicos (podendo ou não existirem) e eu não sei como montar o objeto que vai receber esses dados (não sei nem se é possível receber os dados dessa forma que eu estou descrevendo). Mas valeu.

Comment: você quer submitar o formulário com um objeto pessoa e uma lista de cursos? Se for isso poderá esta submitando o formulário com ajax.